# Why can't I use SOCK_RAW in ai_socktype?

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, raw-sockets

I'm trying to implement an IPv6 UDP client-server application which will let me get the details of the Hop by Hop extension header. So for this I suppose I have to use SOCK_RAW to get access to the IPv6 header information.

Now in my client code, I have the following

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <netdb.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>

   #define BUF_SIZE 500

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       struct addrinfo hints;
       struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
       int sfd, s, j;
       size_t len;
       ssize_t nread;
       char buf[BUF_SIZE];

       if (argc < 3) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port msg...\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       /* Obtain address(es) matching host/port */

       memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
       hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
       hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_RAW; /* Datagram socket */
       hints.ai_flags = 0;
       hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */

       s = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result);
       if (s != 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
          Try each address until we successfully connect(2).
          If socket(2) (or connect(2)) fails, we (close the socket
          and) try the next address. */

       for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
           sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
                        rp->ai_protocol);
           if (sfd == -1)
               continue;

           if (connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
               break;                  /* Success */

           close(sfd);
       }

       if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
           fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */

       /* Send remaining command-line arguments as separate
          datagrams, and read responses from server */

       for (j = 3; j < argc; j++) {
           len = strlen(argv[j]) + 1;
                   /* +1 for terminating null byte */

           if (len + 1 > BUF_SIZE) {
               fprintf(stderr,
                       "Ignoring long message in argument %d\n", j);
               continue;
           }

           if (write(sfd, argv[j], len) != len) {
               fprintf(stderr, "partial/failed write\n");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           nread = read(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
           if (nread == -1) {
               perror("read");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           printf("Received %ld bytes: %s\n", (long) nread, buf);
       }

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

I know I have not made up the headers for the packet when using SOCK_RAW..I just wanted to do a dry run to see what is the error I get. It fails in the getaddrinfo() giving the following error,

getaddrinfo(): servname not supported for ai_socktype

My concern is, it should not fail here rather when it is sending some data to the socket or probably when creating a socket..

What can be the reason for this...??

And for SOCK_RAW when constructing packets in IPv6, do I need to handle the checksums as well or that is done by the kernel. From what I have read so far I came across, handling the checksum calculations has to been done for ICMPv6..

Please let me know whether I have got things right and if I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: Your code works for me on OS/X Mavericks, but only if localhost _and_ the destination host have an IPv6 address configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this fails because you call it with two arguments.

From the man page for getaddrinfo:

> The requested service is not available for the requested socket type.  [...]
>     the error could occur if service was not NULL, and hints.ai_socktype was SOCK_RAW (a socket type that does not support the concept of services).

Just give NULL instead of `argv[2]`

Comment: How come i didn't read that :/  I have been reading the man pages like crazyy to find where I'm wrong. Thanks for that though!
That indeed saved some time :p